# Insert indices to pcl::octree::OctreePointCloudSearch<pcl::PointXYZ> in PCL Library

Tags: c++, 3d, pcl

I'm trying to partitioning & perform some actions to a point cloud using `pcl::octree::OctreePointCloudSearch<pcl::PointXYZ> octree`.

In the method, it provides a public function called

```
setInputCloud(const PointCloudConstPtr &cloud_arg, IndicesConstPtr &indices_arg = IndicesConstPtr ())
```

In the doc, the explanation is used as below.

```
*\brief Provide a pointer to the input data set.
     * \param[in] cloud_arg the const boost shared pointer to a PointCloud message
     * \param[in] indices_arg the point indices subset that is to be used from \a cloud - if 0 the whole point cloud is used
```

Further,

```
// public typedefs
typedef boost::shared_ptr<const std::vector<int> > IndicesConstPtr;
typedef pcl::PointCloud<PointT> PointCloud;
typedef boost::shared_ptr<const PointCloud> PointCloudConstPtr;
```

What I have already done is,

```
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr inputCloud (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> ());
pcl::PointIndices::Ptr cloudIndices(new pcl::PointIndices());
pcl::PointIndices::Ptr selectedIndices(new pcl::PointIndices());

/* some code to fill inputCloud and cloudIndices & selectedIndices
(selectedIndices is contains only chosen indices set from all cloudIndices) */

float resolution = 0.1;
pcl::octree::OctreePointCloudSearch<pcl::PointXYZ> octree(resolution);
octree.setInputCloud(inputCloud);
octree.addPointsFromInputCloud();
```

This works fine. But I need, without creating a new point cloud with `selectedIndices`, to use the existing `inputCloud` and use `selectedIndices` to the function.

I know `octree.setInputCloud(inputCloud, selectedIndices);` function is not working. It returns

```
error: cannot convert ‘pcl::PointIndices::Ptr’ {aka ‘std::shared_ptr<pcl::PointIndices>’} to ‘const IndicesConstPtr&’ {aka ‘const std::shared_ptr<const std::vector<int> >&’}
  169 |     octree.setInputCloud (inputCloud,selectedIndices);
      |                                             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                                             |
      |                                             pcl::PointIndices::Ptr {aka std::shared_ptr<pcl::PointIndices>}
```

Do I need to convert `std::shared_ptr<pcl::PointIndices>const to std::shared_ptr<const std::vector<int> >&`? How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution to the above question.

PCL Function

```
 setInputCloud(const PointCloudConstPtr &cloud_arg, IndicesConstPtr &indices_arg = IndicesConstPtr ())
```

accepts indices but you have to convert it to the `pcl::IndicesPtr` type.

So, My solution was to,

```
pcl::IndicesPtr indicesTemp(new std::vector<int>());
std::copy(selectedIndices->indices.begin(), selectedIndices->indices.end(), std::back_inserter(*indicesTemp));

float resolution = 0.1;
pcl::octree::OctreePointCloudSearch<pcl::PointXYZ> octree(resolution);
octree.setInputCloud(inputCloud,indicesTemp);
octree.addPointsFromInputCloud();
```

and results were as expected.